# Gradle repository

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

Sorry, I'm either stupid, or Gradle repository management is really not there where it should be. I have an Eclipse (Mars) workspace with a mix of Maven and Gradle projects. Naturally, before committing anything on our VCS, I want to test locally. This means I *mvn clean install* an Artifact in order to have it in my local Maven repository. Obviously, part of the needed Artifact required by Gradle project are also on remote repository.

My Gradle repo are configured like this:

```
repositories {
mavenLocal()
maven { url "http://myrepo.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/" }
maven { url 
 "http://myrepo.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/" }
maven { url 
 "http://myrepo.mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
maven { url "http://myrepo.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public-
snapshots/" }   
}
```

Why Gradle goes fetch a resource until the last repo? I mean, I updated an Arifact, installed it locally ... obviously the Artifact which is on a remote repo is not yet the latest version ... why does Gradle go and fetch it?

Comment: Does the version end in `-SNAPSHOT`? Are you sure the version in your `build.gradle` is the same as the version you installed locally? Please show the dependency declaration in your `build.gradle` and also the logging in the console of the dependency being downloaded

Comment: Because the first, the second, the third repository hasn't needed dependencies. the last has needed dependencies.